# dropdown menu get selected value javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

**trying to get selected value:**

```
getSelectedValue = () => {
        let selectedValue = document.getElementsByClassName('aa');
        selectedValue.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        console.log(selectedValue);
      };
```

how can I do to make bold the value (text) that the user selected in the drop down menu

when the user navigate in the menu, i need to make the value his selected in the menu bold.

how can i do this??

HTML code below:

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="showMenu()" class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
            <div id="menuDrop" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">O QUE É A MICOSE DE UNHA?</a>
              <a href="#aspecto">QUAL O ASPECTO DE UMA MICOSE DE UNHA?</a>
              <a href="#possiveis">POSSÍVEIS CAUSAS DA MICOSE DE UNHA</a>
              <a href="#">OPÇÕES DE TRATAMENTO PARA MICOSE DE UNHA</a>
              <a href="#">FATOS RÁPIDOS SOBRE A MICOSE DE UNHA</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS code below:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

function showMenu (javascript) below:

```
showMenu = () => {
        document.getElementById('menuDrop').classList.toggle('show');
      };

      window.onclick = (event) => {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
          let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
          for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
              openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @WaisKamal nothing, I think in use getElementById, but how can I change css to bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented out the line - `openDropdown.classList.remove('show')` and added the script for adding / removing the `active` class..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-content a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-content a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });    
});

showMenu = () => {
        document.getElementById('menuDrop').classList.toggle('show');
      };

      window.onclick = (event) => {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
          let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
          for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            /*if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
              openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }*/
          }
        }
      };
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  /*right: 0;*/ /*remove it*/
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* add it */

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*********************/

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="showMenu()" class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
            <div id="menuDrop" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">O QUE É A MICOSE DE UNHA?</a>
              <a href="#aspecto">QUAL O ASPECTO DE UMA MICOSE DE UNHA?</a>
              <a href="#possiveis">POSSÍVEIS CAUSAS DA MICOSE DE UNHA</a>
              <a href="#">OPÇÕES DE TRATAMENTO PARA MICOSE DE UNHA</a>
              <a href="#">FATOS RÁPIDOS SOBRE A MICOSE DE UNHA</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: it works, but when happens the navigation from href, the bold disappears

Comment: do you use ajax to follow links from href?

Comment: no, I updated my question with the way I am trying, Can you help me with it??

Comment: ok. when you follow the links, is the whole dom structure loaded, or is the content loaded into the container?

Comment: its loaded into the container, reload not happens when I follow the links

Comment: if so, then it can be done with an ordinary counter. I'll make the code now

Comment: check my amendments, please